# Reorganize Dataframe to Multi Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe after I appended the data from different sources of files:

```
              Owed    Due     Date
Input         NaN    51.83  08012019
Net           NaN    35.91  08012019
Output        NaN   -49.02  08012019
Total       -1.26    38.72  08012019
Input         NaN    58.43  09012019
Net           NaN     9.15  09012019
Output        NaN   -57.08  09012019
Total       -3.48    10.50  09012019
Input         NaN    66.50  10012019
Net           NaN     9.64  10012019
Output        NaN   -64.70  10012019
Total       -5.16    11.44  10012019
```

I have been trying to figure out how to reorganize this dataframe to become multi index like this:

[image]

I have tried to use melt and pivot but with limited success to even reshape anything. Will appreciate for some guidance!

P.S: The date when using print(df) shows DD for date (e.g 08). However if I change this to a csv file, it becomes 8 instead of 08 for single digit day. Hope someone can guide me on this too, thanks.

Comment: Please post your data as text, not pictures, so we can load it.

Comment: Please advice if there is a fast way to add my raw table into the post in text format because if I copy and paste my table from excel to my post (block or code), it became an image. Thanks.

Comment: Just use `print(df)` to print the table, and copy-paste the text into your question.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know I can do this lol. Thanks for the advice, I have modified my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df.set_index('Date', append=True).unstack(0).dropna(axis=1)
```

`set_index()` moves Date to become an additional index column.  Then `unstack(0)` moves the original index to become column names.  Finally, drop the NAN columns and you have your desired result.